# Rails: Getting an array of object ids by query/conversion (for comparision)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, optimization

Basically, I want an array of ids from the database.

Some background:

- I'm rendering a list of objets (foos) to the user with a checkbox.
- If the user checks the box a row is create in a different table (bar)
- when rendering the foo list + checkbox I want to check if the unique id any given foo already exists in the bar id array.

I assumed that getting an array of ids would be much more efficient than querying the database for each instance of foo when rendering the foo list with checkboxes.

Ideas? Apologies in advance if this is not clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used the map method:

```
@bars = Bar.all(:select => bar.id)
@bars = @bars.map{|bar| bar.id}
```

Then I end up with array of ids. And only one query.

Comment: This is extremely memory inefficient because it instantiates all `Bar` records in Ruby's memory, just to get a single column. You're better off using `#pluck` e.g. `Bar.all.pluck(:id)` which returns a list of the IDs.

Answer (score 14):

we can use the map method also this way

```
Model.all.map(&:field_name)
```

Answer (score 8):

More recent versions of Rails support `Model.pluck(:field_name)`

Answer (score 1):

```
array1 = User.all.collect(&:id)
```

The `array1` has the values of all the ids in the table `Users`.

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem, than? If you have rails `has_many` or `has_and_belongs_to_many` association, rails will fetch ids for you. See [relevant tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference) for details, in short it's like `@order_ids = @customer.order_ids`.

Otherwise, you can easily use plain sql (or active record query).

Comment: I am aware of has_many,etc. But again, you're making an association query for each foo, that doesn't seem as efficient as pre-fetching all the bar ids and then comparing.

Comment: @cbrulak When you invoke 'order_ids', rails don't run query for each result. And again, you can always switch to sql: "select id from my_table where ...".